# Web Server not serving audio file to every browser

Tags: c, web, server

The following is the communication between a web server I made in C and Internet Explorer. Everything is served but the audio file. Any insight as to why only the audio never gets served?

```
GET /castle/media/witchwoode.m4a HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:6006/castle/index.html
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1
Pragma: getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 127.0.0.1:6006
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: web
Content-Length: 3017451
Connection: close
Content-Type: audio/mp4
```

Comment: Is your program the server or the client or both?  At the very least, we need to see the source of the client (and if a home grown server, then the code of the server)

Comment: I made a web server and just used Internet Explorer, chrome, and firefox to test it. I'll post the code, but this site limited my initial code in the above question.

Comment: then post the server code, with out an extranious bells and whistles.  Remember it must cleanly compile and still show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I download the example m4a-file from [techslides](http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.m4a) I get the following response:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Sat, 25 Jun 2016 02:35:31 GMT
  Content-Type: audio/mpeg
  Content-Length: 34535
  Last-Modified: Sun, 16 Feb 2014 18:49:36 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "53010840-86e7"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

As you can see: a different Content-Type and Connection.

BTW: Firefox says something about a corrupt file, but both Chrome with the above adress and a stand-alone player (mplayer) with the downloaded file work just fine, so before you hassle with the code, try a change of the protocol.

Comment: Thank You, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I changed the content type and changed the order of each response item to the order you used and now it works with every browser, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Well its not working. Here is part of the code where I think problem is.

**range**, is a int to determine when "Range" is found.
**ctype**, based on the file extension in the GET.
**header**, buffer to hold the header.
**out**, malloced memory used for data sent to browser.
**out2**, malloced memory used to hold **header** and **out** then send.
**isize**, is a int size of **out**.
**datasize**, char string representation of **isize**.

```
if ( range == 0 )
{                            
    strcpy(header,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: web\r\nContent-Type: ");
}
else
{
    strcpy(header,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: web\r\nAccept-Ranges: none\r\nContent-Type: ");
}                            
strcat(header,ctype);
strcat(header,"\r\nContent-Length: ");
strcat(header,datasize);
strcat(header,"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
printf("%s",header);
printf("\nlength of header: %d\n", strlen(header));                           
out2 = malloc( sizeof(char)*(isize+1+strlen(header)) ); 
memcpy(out2,header,strlen(header));
memcpy(&out2[strlen(header)],out,isize);
free(out);

send(sd,out2,isize+strlen(header),0);
free(out2);
```